# Prove that if $G=\langle x\rangle$ for every $x\in G\setminus \{1_G\}$, then $|G|$ is prime

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am trying to prove that the following statements are equivalent:

(i) the group $G$ is generated by every element of the group, except the neutral element

(ii) $G$ is trivial or $|G|$ is prime

I used Lagrange to go from (ii) to (i), but I am having trouble proving that (i) implies (ii). If $G$ is cyclic for every $x$ in $G$, why does the order have to be a prime number?

Comment: Do you assume knowledge of the Sylow theorems?

Comment: As this is a claim that is in my course before Cauchy's theorem and the Sylow theorems, I assume I should be able to prove it without using those.

Comment: The claim is that G is generated by each of its elements.

Comment: @VickyG Do you see why this is different from (i)? You should correct your statement (i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ has non-prime order, so $|G|=mn$ for $m, n>1$, and let $G=\langle x\rangle$.

Then can $\langle x^m\rangle=G$?